# Microsoft Access 2007 -- View Query Used In Report?

Tags: ms-access, reporting, ms-access-2007

I need help navigating Microsoft Access Reports. 
I am in the Report Designer, and I need to know the which menu selection will enable me to view the Query that was used in the report.

I have never used Access before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open the report in design mode.
Press F4, you will be able to see the dropdown in the "Properties" window.
Choose "Report" from the dropdown. You will see the "Record Source" property below it.

That contains the query/table which is used to build the report.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks